# How to search from/to/subject/all fields in Apple Mail 5?

Tags: apple-mail, osx-lion

I just upgraded to OS X Lion 10.7 and it included the new Apple Mail.

In Mail 4, I used to be able to choose where to search from (from/to/subject/all). How do I do this in Mail 5?

Comment: I read the help carefully, and I cannot figure out how to narrow the search.

Answer (score 2):

You can use search tokens, e.g.

- from:michael
- to:bob
- subject:hello

For more info please see the [MacLife Article](http://www.maclife.com/article/howtos/how_use_search_tokens_lion_mail) on using search tokens in Lion's Mail.

Answer (score 0):

Start typing someone's name, then (in the search pop-up) select that name from the "people" list. This inserts a token in the search field. Click on this token to change it. You can then narrow the mailbox using the favorites bar.